# What is the optimal speed for handling ranges?

Tags: performance, google-sheets

Let's say I have a Google sheet with tab1 and tab2

in tab 1 I have 2000 rows and 20 columns filled with data and 1000 rows are empty, so I have 3000 rows.

In tab2 I have a few formulas like `vlookup` and some `if` functions.

The options I can think of are:

1. I can name the range of the data in tab1 and use that in the formula(s) and if the range expands, I can edit the range
2. I can use option B:B
3. I can delete the empty rows and use B:B

what is the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all three of those options have no real word effect on the overall performance given that you have only 3000 rows across 20 columns. the biggest impact on performance you can have is from `QUERY`<sub>s</sub>, `IMPORTRANGE`<sub>s</sub> and `ARRAYFORMULA`<sub>s</sub> if fed by a huge amount of data (10000+ rows) or if you have extensive calculations with multiple sub-steps consisting of whole virtual arrays.